# Get local network interface addresses using only proc?

Tags: python, linux, networking, ipv4, procfs

**How can I obtain the (IPv4) addresses for all network interfaces using only [proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)?** After some extensive investigation I've discovered the following:

1. `ifconfig` makes use of `SIOCGIFADDR`, which requires open sockets and advance knowledge of all the interface names. It also isn't documented in any manual pages on Linux.
2. `proc` contains `/proc/net/dev`, but this is a list of interface statistics.
3. `proc` contains `/proc/net/if_inet6`, which is exactly what I need but for IPv6.
4. Generally interfaces are easy to find in `proc`, but actual addresses are very rarely used except where explicitly part of some connection.
5. There's a system call called [`getifaddrs`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getifaddrs/), which is very much a "magical" function you'd expect to see in Windows. It's also implemented on BSD. However it's not very text-oriented, which makes it difficult to use from non-C languages.

Comment: @forest: Because it implies parsable text, dependence on modern Linux, and doesn't require spawning processes.

Comment: I see.  Sadly, I don't know that the /proc data structures you'd need are guaranteed to remain consistent between operating systems or even kernel releases.  (Someone please prove me wrong.)  Meanwhile, the ifconfig and ip programs produce stable output, which is why I ended up choosing to parse it instead of turning to /proc.  Here's an alternative that looks promising:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnet/

Comment: Did you try `iproute2` suite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no IPv4 analog of /proc/net/if_inet6

ifconfig does:

```
fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP)
ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFCONF, ...)
```

You'll get something like this:

```
ioctl(4, SIOCGIFCONF, {120, {{"lo", {AF_INET, inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}}, {"eth0", {AF_INET, inet_addr("10.6.23.69")}}, {"tun0", {AF_INET, inet_addr("10.253.10.151")}}}})
```

Comment: How bizarre. Why do both `SIOCGIFCONF` and `getifaddrs` exist?

Comment: `getifaddrs` is a function provided by the C library (e.g. glibc), while the `SIOCGIFCONF` `ioctl` interface is implemented by kernel and used by the C library to implement `getifaddrs`, although nowadays the much more modern `netlink` interface is used.

Answer (score 32):

`/proc/net/fib_trie` holds the network topography

To simply print the addresses of all adapters:

```
$ awk '/32 host/ { print f } {f=$2}' <<< "$(</proc/net/fib_trie)"
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.5
192.168.1.14
```

To determine the adapter of those addresses (a) consult the adapters' destination networks from `/proc/net/route`, (b) match those networks with the ones of `/proc/net/fib_trie` and (c) print the corresponding /32 host addresses listed under those networks.

Again no `python` unfortunately, but a quite awky `bash` approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

ft_local=$(awk '$1=="Local:" {flag=1} flag' <<< "$(</proc/net/fib_trie)")

for IF in $(ls /sys/class/net/); do
    networks=$(awk '$1=="'$IF'" && $3=="00000000" && $8!="FFFFFFFF" {printf $2 $8 "\n"}' <<< "$(</proc/net/route)" )
    for net_hex in $networks; do
            net_dec=$(awk '{gsub(/../, "0x& "); printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", $4, $3, $2, $1}' <<< $net_hex)
            mask_dec=$(awk '{gsub(/../, "0x& "); printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", $8, $7, $6, $5}' <<< $net_hex)
            awk '/'$net_dec'/{flag=1} /32 host/{flag=0} flag {a=$2} END {print "'$IF':\t" a "\n\t'$mask_dec'\n"}' <<< "$ft_local"
    done
done

exit 0
```

output:

```
eth0:     192.168.0.5
          255.255.255.0

lo:       127.0.0.1
          255.0.0.0

wlan0:    192.168.1.14
          255.255.255.0
```

Known limitation:

This approach does not work reliably for host addresses that share the network with other host addresses. This loss of network uniqueness makes it impossible to determine the correct host address from fib_trie as the order of those addresses does not necessarily match the order of networks of route.

Having said that, I'm not sure why you would want multiple host addresses belonging to the same network in first place. So in most use cases this approach should work just fine.

Comment: How do you match the ip address from fib_trie to the network interface name in /proc/net/route? Inspecting my /proc/net/route, I have multiple entries for the same network interface name. Furthermore, the ip address from fib_trie doesn't seem to match the 'destination' column, which is the IP converted from hex and reverse order, of ANY entries in the route table .

Comment: This file doesn't exist in CentOS 5.

Comment: @Maytas Monsereenusorn Both fib_trie & route have in common that they provide the NETWORK IP address. Generally this network is unique to the HOST IP address. Thus you can link the corresponding interface from route with the corresponding host IP address from fib_trie. You can have multiple host IPs for the same interface, but they should not belong to the same network (see limitation above as to why). Is it possible that you are including host routes when speaking of 'multiple entries for the same network interface name' in /proc/net/route? Those entries are not considered by the script.

Comment: Why ` <<< "$(</proc/...)"` instead of simply `awk '..' </proc/...`

Answer (score 17):

You may find the output of `ip addr show` easier to parse than output from other tools:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:1d:ce:47:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.121/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::224:1dff:fece:4705/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:1d:ce:35:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/ether 92:e3:6c:08:1f:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
    inet6 fe80::90e3:6cff:fe08:1faf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Another option is the file `/proc/net/tcp`. It shows all currently-open TCP sessions, which is different than what you asked for, but might be Good Enough.

```
$ cat tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
   0: 00000000:0050 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 13536 1 ffff88019f0a1380 300 0 0 2 -1
   1: 00000000:1355 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 19877854 1 ffff880016e69380 300 0 0 2 -1
   2: 017AA8C0:0035 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 13633 1 ffff88019f0a1a00 300 0 0 2 -1
   3: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 8971 1 ffff88019f0a0000 300 0 0 2 -1
   4: 0100007F:0277 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 12952880 1 ffff880030e30680 300 0 0 2 -1
   5: 00000000:0539 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 14332 1 ffff88019f0a2080 300 0 0 2 -1
   6: 00000000:C000 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 14334 1 ffff88019f0a2700 300 0 0 2 -1
   7: 0100007F:0A44 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   119        0 51794804 1 ffff880016e6a700 300 0 0 2 -1
   8: 7900A8C0:B094 53D50E48:01BB 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 64877487 1 ffff880100502080 23 4 16 4 -1
   9: 7900A8C0:9576 537F7D4A:01BB 06 00000000:00000000 03:00000E5D 00000000     0        0 0 3 ffff880100c84600
  10: 7900A8C0:CC84 0CC181AE:01BB 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 61775908 1 ffff880198715480 35 4 11 4 -1
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> [0x79, 0x00, 0xa8, 0xc0]
=> [121, 0, 168, 192]
```

My IP is `192.168.0.121`; note the funny arithmetic to make it come out right. :)

Comment: Hmm, ip(1) is nice. It'll be much better to fallback onto than ifconfig, thanks.

Comment: Why not simply: `printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" 0xc0 0xa8 0x00 0x79` (I've tested, this work under bash, dash, zsh, csh and ksh.)

Comment: @F.Hauri, the actual printing method for hex->decimal doesn't much matter. What does matter is that the `0x79 0x00..` is given in my abuse of `irb` in the same order as the last entries in `/proc/net/tcp`. Reversing the bytes, as you've done, I think makes it harder to spot the data that you're looking for and how to fix it. Of course, if you're writing a portable script, `printf(1)` is the way to go. :) But here `irb` is just used for illustration. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

#### My solution to retrieve IPv4 network config, using `/proc` only:

Unfortunately, this is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (*bash only* and *without* any fork), not [python](/questions/tagged/python). But I hope this will be readable:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# ip functions that set variables instead of returning to STDOUT

hexToInt() {
    printf -v $1 "%d\n" 0x${2:6:2}${2:4:2}${2:2:2}${2:0:2}
}
intToIp() {
    local var=$1 iIp
    shift
    for iIp ;do 
        printf -v $var "%s %s.%s.%s.%s" "${!var}" $(($iIp>>24)) \
            $(($iIp>>16&255)) $(($iIp>>8&255)) $(($iIp&255))
    done
}
maskLen() {
    local i
    for ((i=0; i<32 && ( 1 & $2 >> (31-i) ) ;i++));do :;done
    printf -v $1 "%d" $i
}
```

```bash
# The main loop.
while read -a rtLine ;do
    if [ ${rtLine[2]} == "00000000" ] && [ ${rtLine[7]} != "00000000" ] ;then
        hexToInt netInt  ${rtLine[1]}
        hexToInt maskInt ${rtLine[7]}
        if [ $((netInt&maskInt)) == $netInt ] ;then
            for procConnList in /proc/net/{tcp,udp} ;do
                while IFS=': \t\n' read -a conLine ;do
                    if [[ ${conLine[1]} =~ ^[0-9a-fA-F]*$ ]] ;then
                        hexToInt ipInt ${conLine[1]}
                        [ $((ipInt&maskInt)) == $netInt ] && break 3
                    fi
                done < $procConnList
            done
        fi
    fi
done < /proc/net/route
```

```bash
# And finaly the printout of what's found
maskLen maskBits $maskInt
intToIp addrLine $ipInt $netInt $maskInt
printf -v outForm '%-12s: %%s\\n' Interface Address Network Netmask Masklen
printf "$outForm" $rtLine $addrLine $maskBits\ bits
```

There is a sample of output:

```
Interface   : eth0
Address     : 192.168.1.32
Network     : 192.168.1.0
Netmask     : 255.255.255.0
Masklen     : 24 bits
```

Explanation:

I use integer value of IPV4 in order to check `IP & MASK == NETWORK`.

I read first `/proc/net/route` to find routing configurations, searching for routes reachable without any gateway (`gw==000000`).

For such a route, I search in all connections (TCP, than UDP if not found in TCP) for connection using **this** route, the first end point is my host address.

Nota: This won't work with PPP connections

Nota2: This won't work on a totally quiet host without any opened network connection.
You could do something like `echo -ne '' | nc -q 0 -w 1 8.8.8.8 80 & sleep .2 && ./retrieveIp.sh` for ensuring that something where found in `/proc/net/tcp`.

Nota3, 2016-09.23: New [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version use  `>(command)` syntax for `multiple inline pipe` *feature*. This implie a bug at line 18: a space **must** be present between `>` and `(` !!

#### New version with *gateway*

There is a little patch: Once you create a file called `getIPv4.sh` by copying previous script, you could paste the following to the command: `patch -p0`

```
--- getIPv4.sh
+++ getIPv4.sh
@@ -35,13 +35,16 @@
                 done < $procConnList
             done
         fi
+    elif [ ${rtLine[1]} == "00000000" ] && [ ${rtLine[7]} == "00000000" ] ;then
+       hexToInt netGw ${rtLine[2]}
     fi
 done < /proc/net/route 

 # And finaly the printout of what's found

 maskLen maskBits $maskInt
-intToIp addrLine $ipInt $netInt $maskInt
-printf -v outForm '%-12s: %%s\\n' Interface Address Network Netmask Masklen
+intToIp addrLine $ipInt $netInt $netGw $maskInt
+printf -v outForm '%-12s: %%s\\n' \
+       Interface Address Network Gateway Netmask Masklen
 printf "$outForm" $rtLine $addrLine $maskBits\ bits
```

End with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, this may output:

```
patching file getIPv4.sh
```

And maybe

```
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 with fuzz 2.
```

Then re-run your script:

```
getIPv4.sh
Interface   : eth0
Address     : 192.168.1.32
Network     : 192.168.1.0
Gateway     : 192.168.1.1
Netmask     : 255.255.255.0
Masklen     : 24 bits
```

Comment: There's no need to do any of the `export` statements in your script. For integer comparisons, you should use the form `if (( expr == num ))` instead of `if [ $((expr)) == $num ]`. For other `if` statements, you should use double square brackets instead of single.

Comment: `export` isn't needed when you `source` this script, either. It would only be needed if the variables and functions were to be used in child processes of this script. Using the correct Bash form for comparisons simplifies the statements, makes their meaning more clear and provides additional functionality and robustness.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Did you notice that new `>(...)` bashism make this not work anymore... A space is to be added after `>` ! ... :-/

Answer (score 5):

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | grep "inet " | cut -d ' ' -f 6  | cut -f 1 -d '/'
```

Comment: Saved a 'grep'  by adding more switches to ip:  `ip -o -4 addr show dev eth0 | cut -d ' ' -f 7  | cut -f 1 -d '/'` -o for one-line, -4 to show ipv4 only

Comment: This isn't helpful as the OP asked for a way using only the /proc filesystem!

Answer (score 4):

hers a fancy one i found somewhere in the internet. minorly fixed it up to fit and correctly output tun (vpn) devices.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from socket import AF_INET, AF_INET6, inet_ntop
from ctypes import (
    Structure, Union, POINTER, 
    pointer, get_errno, cast,
    c_ushort, c_byte, c_void_p, c_char_p, c_uint, c_int, c_uint16, c_uint32
)
import ctypes.util
import ctypes

class struct_sockaddr(Structure):
     _fields_ = [
        ('sa_family', c_ushort),
        ('sa_data', c_byte * 14),]

class struct_sockaddr_in(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('sin_family', c_ushort),
        ('sin_port', c_uint16),
        ('sin_addr', c_byte * 4)]

class struct_sockaddr_in6(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('sin6_family', c_ushort),
        ('sin6_port', c_uint16),
        ('sin6_flowinfo', c_uint32),
        ('sin6_addr', c_byte * 16),
        ('sin6_scope_id', c_uint32)]

class union_ifa_ifu(Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ('ifu_broadaddr', POINTER(struct_sockaddr)),
        ('ifu_dstaddr', POINTER(struct_sockaddr)),]

class struct_ifaddrs(Structure):
    pass

struct_ifaddrs._fields_ = [
    ('ifa_next', POINTER(struct_ifaddrs)),
    ('ifa_name', c_char_p),
    ('ifa_flags', c_uint),
    ('ifa_addr', POINTER(struct_sockaddr)),
    ('ifa_netmask', POINTER(struct_sockaddr)),
    ('ifa_ifu', union_ifa_ifu),
    ('ifa_data', c_void_p),]

libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))

def ifap_iter(ifap):
    ifa = ifap.contents
    while True:
        yield ifa
        if not ifa.ifa_next:
            break
        ifa = ifa.ifa_next.contents

def getfamaddr(sa):
    family = sa.sa_family
    addr = None
    if family == AF_INET:
        sa = cast(pointer(sa), POINTER(struct_sockaddr_in)).contents
        addr = inet_ntop(family, sa.sin_addr)
    elif family == AF_INET6:
        sa = cast(pointer(sa), POINTER(struct_sockaddr_in6)).contents
        addr = inet_ntop(family, sa.sin6_addr)
    return family, addr

class NetworkInterface(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.index = libc.if_nametoindex(name)
        self.addresses = {}
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s [index=%d, IPv4=%s, IPv6=%s]" % (
            self.name, self.index,
            self.addresses.get(AF_INET),
            self.addresses.get(AF_INET6))

def get_network_interfaces():
    ifap = POINTER(struct_ifaddrs)()
    result = libc.getifaddrs(pointer(ifap))
    if result != 0:
        raise OSError(get_errno())
    del result
    try:
        retval = {}
        for ifa in ifap_iter(ifap):
            name = ifa.ifa_name
            i = retval.get(name)
            if not i:
                i = retval[name] = NetworkInterface(name)
            try:
                family, addr = getfamaddr(ifa.ifa_addr.contents)
            except ValueError:
                family, addr = None, None
            if addr:
                i.addresses[family] = addr
        return retval.values()
    finally:
        libc.freeifaddrs(ifap)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print [str(ni) for ni in get_network_interfaces()]
```

Comment: Old as gold, but here's a slight modification to support netmasks and bump to Python3: https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/blob/26027d5db566083b30e599a04292bb696418a526/python/get_network_interfaces.py

Answer (score 3):

cat /proc/net/tcp

Get the second column, with the heading "local_address", e.g. "CF00A8C0:0203"

The part after ":" is a port number.

From the rest use the last two (C0) as a hex number, e.g. C0 is 192, which is the start of the address in this example.

Took the following into my notes a while ago, from some smart point in the net:

The IP address is displayed as a little-endian four-byte hexadecimal number;
 that is, the least significant byte is listed first,
 so you'll need to reverse the order of the bytes to convert it to an IP address.

The port number is a simple two-byte hexadecimal number.

Comment: Like :

    tail -n1 /proc/net/tcp
   7: 1002000A:65F5 0202000A:DBEA 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 13951 3 de559e00 21 4 11 10 -1                            

printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" 0x10 0x02 0x00 0x0A
16.2.0.10

Answer (score 1):

```
ip -j -o -4 addr show dev eth0 | jq .[1].addr_info[0].local
```

Comment: "all network interfaces", I don't even have eth0 on my system

Comment: OP wants a method to gather this info using `/proc`, not actual cmds.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of /proc/net/tcp as on a system I have here, I use keepalived to bring up an additional IP address on the preferred host, but when I checked, that address wasn't represented in /proc/net/tcp, but it is present in /proc/net/fib_trie

Answer (score 0):

In [miniss](https://github.com/noraj/miniss) I display the list of open listening sockets by reading `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/tcp6`, `/proc/net/udp`, `/proc/net/udp6` instead of using `ss` or `netstat`.
Your issue is similar, where you want to read some files in `/proc/net/` instead of using `ip` or `ifconfig`.

In most `/proc/net/`, IP addresses are hex encoded in a specific way (see [the crystal source code here to see how to decode them](https://github.com/noraj/miniss/blob/master/src/miniss/addr.cr), that could be reproduced in python).

As said by others, there is the convenient `/proc/self/net/if_inet6` for IPv6 but no equivalent for IPv4. So for IPv4 you could make a map between `/proc/net/fib_trie` and `/proc/net/route` on the network. The hardest is parsing IP addresses but I just gave you the source code to do so.

Answer (score -1):

It's bass-ackwards and I probably am forgetting a corner case, but if you look at /proc/1/net/route, that has your routing table.  If you select lines for which the gateway is 0.0.0.0, the first column is the interface and the second column is the hex representation of your IP address, in network byte order (and the third column is the gateway ip you want to filter on).

Comment: The second column isn't the IP address but rather the network address, so this won't work, unfortunately.