# expect script: parse ip address from ifconfig

Tags: parsing, exec, expect

I am trying to parse the IP address from ifconfig command.  It works fine when I do it on the command line

```
pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$ ifconfig enp0s3 | sed -n '/inet addr/s/.*addr.\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p'
192.168.1.112
```

But it gives error when I use it in a expect script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set pidBash [ spawn bash ]

set ipIfConfig {ifconfig enp0s3 | sed -n '/inet addr/s/.*addr.\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p'}
set clientIP [exec "echo $ipIfConfig"]
puts "clientIP = $clientIP" 
exit 1
```

The output is

```
pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$ ./ifconfig_parse.sh 
spawn bash
couldn't execute "echo ifconfig enp0s3 | sed -n '/inet addr/s/.*addr.\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p'": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec "echo $ipIfConfig""
    invoked from within
"set clientIP [exec "echo $ipIfConfig"]"
    (file "./ifconfig_parse.sh" line 7)
```

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281341/get-local-network-interface-addresses-using-only-proc) help?

Comment: Try "bash ifconfig_parse.sh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
set ip [exec ifconfig enp0s3 | sed -n {/inet addr/s/.*addr.\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p}]
puts ip=$ip
```

See [Command substitution](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) and [exec](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) in [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/)'s manual.

Comment: You should explain why, single quotes vs braces.

Comment: @whjm Thanks.  Have to be careful when to use quotes vs. braces.  I was able to also extract the IP address without using 'sed' using this

if {[regexp {inet addr:(\S+)} [exec ifconfig enp0s3] -> clientIP]} { puts "clientIP = $clientIP" }

Answer (score 0):

Here a concise and simple awk script to extract ip

For `ip4`:

```
ifconfig eno1 |awk '/inet /{print $2}'
```

For `ip6`

```
ifconfig eno1 |awk '/inet6/{print $2}'
```

For both `ip4` and `ip6`

ifconfig eno1 |awk '/inet/{print $2}'

Essentially the script should be:

```
set ip [ ifconfig eno1 |awk '/inet /{print $2}' ]
```